# Monero wallet on Linux Elementary OS

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I installed wallet Monero on Linux  Elementary OS and I have a problem. I don't have app in my applications. I have only folder /home/user/Monero/
How can I use my wallet if I don't have app?

It is my first time. I am learning about cryptocurrency.

Comment: Open a new terminal from the same directory as `monero-wallet-gui`. Subsequently type -> `./start-gui.sh`

Comment: ok, it works :) But it will be always? I want to app for this.

Comment: I am not sure, it might. Note that you can always request it by opening a new issue on the Monero GUI [Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui). I've also added my comment as an answer. Please mark it as "answered" if you feel it has sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: Ok, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the GUI isn't distributed as an app. Thus, it has to be started from the terminal. As Linux Elementary is based on Ubuntu, simply perform these steps:

1. Browse to the directory `monero-wallet-gui` is located.
2. Open a new terminal.
3. Type -> `./start-gui.sh`

You should now be able to use the GUI.